# Jenkins build with ant: exec returned: 1 with phpunit?

Tags: php, ant, build, jenkins, phpunit

I'm new to jenkins and I try to execute some code analyis together with ant. I used the build XML from this tutorial http://jenkins-php.org/.
But I always got an error like this:

```
/var/www/ekc/build.xml:117:exec returned: 2
```

So I used this Solution: [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430740/ant-f-build-xml-exec-returned-2-with-phpunit)

But now I get this Error:

```
/var/www/ekc/build.xml:117:exec returned: 1
```

Here is my build.xml

```
 <target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
  <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true">
     <arg line="--log-junit ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml serving" />
  </exec>
 </target>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: your phpunit test fails with exit code 1. Try to find out why your unit test fail.

Comment: In build console output you should see what happened